# How can a process get to know the message queue descriptor for the queue created by another process?

Tags: posix, ipc, message-queue

A POSIX message queue can be created by mq_open() which returns message queue descriptor of the form mqd_t. If some other process has to receive the message via mq_notify() or mq_receive(), it needs message queue descriptor as an argument.

Is there a way to get message queue descriptor using the queue name?

If not, how is the message queue descriptor communicated to the other process before it can begin using message queues?

Answer (score 0):

```
 mqd_t mq_open(const char *name, int oflag);
```

The message queue is identified by the two processes by the "name", i.e. the first     argument in call to mq_open.
The two processes that intend to share the message queue must know, the name of the queue      to be shared, in advance.

If you use

```
int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg);
```

key : user defined value.
The the value of "key" here identifies a message queue across multiple processes.

To sum up :
If two processes need to share a message queue, they need to know the "name" (in case of
mq_open) and "key"(in case of msgget) in advance.